# C# - Override <T> method signature with ClassName?

Tags: overriding, type-conversion, method-signature

Is there a way to override an abstract class's method signature which uses `<T>` with a ClassName so I can pass an object by reference without recasting it?

For example, I have a bunch of Object Managers. I want them all to contain a .Save(Object) method which will perform the appropriate save action based on the object state (Insert, Update, Delete, etc).

I was trying to create a base class which contains these methods:

```
protected virtual bool Update<T>(ref T _object) where T : ObjectBase
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public virtual bool Save<T>(ref T _object) where T : ObjectBase
{ 
    // Figure out which action to take based on _object's state and execute it
}
```

And I wanted my inherited classes to define the methods using something like this:

```
public override bool Update<Consumer>(ref Consumer _object)
{
    return _service.UpdateConsumer(ref _object);
}
```

My problem is that I can't specify that `<T>` will now be `<Consumer>`, and by keeping it at `<T>` I can't pass it by ref

Comment: Why would you need to specify `ref`? It is almost certainly a reference object anyway. A matter of opinion, but I'd say `ref` is bad form.

Comment: that isn't what ref means... ref means that the actual reference is being passed.  So that if he were to change the value of _object to a different object, it would be reflected in the callers reference of _object.  But in this case, i see no hint of a reason for him to be doing so.

Comment: I was passing by reference because the _service is a WCF service and it changes the object properties based on database inputs/outputs.

Comment: @Brian Right; the intention though appears to be to make sure that the caller's reference is updated by the method, which one would do when passing a value object (also a valid, if not pretty, use of `ref`).

Comment: Yes I wanted to be sure the caller's reference to the variable was updated when I updated it on the WCF server. I haven't really used ref much, the only time I did was in a project done in VB. If you know of a better way of doing it let me know :)

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you're saying... didn't know by default classes were reference types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of making the methods themselves generic, you should make the entire base class generic.

For example:

```
public abstract class ObjectManager<T> where T : ObjectBase {
    protected abstract bool Update(T obj);
}
```

Each concrete ObjectManager should inherit `ObjectManager` of the type that it manages, like this:

```
public class ConsumerManager : ObjectManager<Consumer> {
    protected override bool Update(Consumer obj) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note, by the way, that your parameters should almost definitely not be passed `ref`.
You only need to `ref` keyword if you want to change the *caller*'s variable to refer to a *different instance*.
For more information, see [here](http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/01/parameter-passing-in-c.html).

Comment: What do you mean? The two sets of code are in separate classes, with the derived classes inheriting from the base class. I just excluded the class definition because I was trying to simplify the code.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware I could do that.

Comment: @Rachel He means that if you put `<T>` on the class, instead of the method, then all of your methods in the derived class will use the type you want. `public abstract void UpdateThing(T thing)` in the base class will become `public void UpdateThing(Consumer thing)` in the derived class.